# merge 2 ArrayLists based on a common variable

Tags: java, join

I have two separate arrayLists. For example:

```
array1 = [[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
array2 = [[3 7 8 9 10 11 16]]
```

I want to have an arraylist like below:

```
arrayResult = [[1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 16]]
```

There is a mutual variable on two arraylists and I want to have the first part of array1 + second part of array2 in a new arraylist.

Comment: no collections allowed, isn it??

Comment: what do u mean by collection?! there is no difference! @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: You can use `TreeSet` for this. Which avoids duplicates and keeps data in sorted form

Comment: I mean that the title of the question is using the word ***ArrayList*** which has an specific meaning in java....

Comment: But you can convert It into TreeSet

Comment: Can you post your datastructures? Something you tried? Is this `List`? array? `Set`?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ it is important to be arrayLists! I have worked the project based on this structure! and I dont wanna convert it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the first `List` and check the value at each index of the first `List` for existence in the second `List`. If the value does not exist add the first `List` value, if it does exists then copy the remaining values from the second `List`.

```
List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(3,7,8,9,10,11,16);
List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();//joined List
for ( int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++ ){
    int index = l2.indexOf(l1.get(i));
    if ( index == -1 ){
        l3.add(l1.get(i));
    }else{
        for ( int j = index; j < l2.size(); j++ ){
            l3.add(l2.get(j));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do `l3.addAll(l2.subList(index, l2.size()))` without the for loop also, and use a enhanced for loop over `l1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's Merge Sort Problem. Try applying the merge sort algorithm. Check this for more clarity and code snap :[Merge Sort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_algorithm.htm)

Else try this :

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1); 

List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(array2); 

set.addAll(list1);
set.addAll(list2);

yourResult = set.toArray();
```

Comment: The problem isn't sorting - it involves is using portions of each list, joining them at a cross-over point defined by the index of equal values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> a2 = Arrays.asList(3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16);
ArrayList<Integer> merged = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer val: a1){
    if(val == a2.get(0)){
        for(Integer val2: a2){
            merged.add(val2);
        }
        break;
    }
    merged.add(val);
}
System.out.println(merged);
```

You'll have to make sure that the second list contains at least 1 value and you'll have to sort the lists if they aren't already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the elements of array1 and each time check if they are in array2.  If not, add them and continue array1's loop.  If it exists in array2, then stop looping array1 and start looping array2 at that index.

This should help..

```
Boolean found = false;
integer foundInd = 0;
Boolean useArray1 = false;
if (array1.length >= array2.length)
    useArray1 = true

For (integer cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < array1.length; cnt1 ++)
{
    For (integer cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < array2.length; cnt2 ++)
    {
        if (array1[cnt1] == array2[cnt2])
        {
            found = true;
            foundInd = cnt2;
        }
    }
    if (useArray1 == false)
        Array2[cnt] = Array1[cnt];
    if (found == true)
        break;
}

For (integer cnt2 = foundInd; cnt2 < array2.length; cnt2 ++)
{
    if (useArray1 == true)
        useArray1[foundInd + cnt2] = array2[cnt2];
}
```

**Side Note-** Rather than creating a new array to store the values, I just used either array1 or array2 depending on which was longer.  It will already have the correct length and at least half of its data will already be the correct number in the  correct location.

Answer (score 0):

if you use collections then you can get both list together and find the common element pretty much easier...

look at this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> a2 = Arrays.asList(3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16);
List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<>();
int commonw;
// merge both and find common Element.class..
// IllegalMonitorStateException must be one
common.addAll(a1);
common.retainAll(a2);
commonw = common.get(0);
common.clear();

// fill the common elements
for (int i = 0; i < a1.indexOf(commonw); i++) {
    common.add(a1.get(i));
}
for (int i = a2.indexOf(commonw) + 1; i < a2.size(); i++) {
    common.add(a2.get(i));
}
System.out.println(common);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have java8 you can try

```
public List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
    Integer integerToMergeAt = first.stream().filter(i -> second.indexOf(i) >= 0).findFirst().get();
    return Stream.concat(first.stream().limit(first.indexOf(integerToMergeAt)),
            second.stream().skip(second.indexOf(integerToMergeAt))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```